# How I can build this json object with javascript code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
{  
   "ma.addEvents":{  
      "ma.id":"my-id",
      "ma.eventIds":[  
         "eventID1",
         "eventID2"
      ]
   }
}
```

I don't understand how I can create object like "ma.addEvent"
the "dot" is a problem here.

Comment: is there a reason you can't nix the ma?

Comment: It's as simple as `var foo = {"ma.addEvents": {"ma.id":"my-id", "ma.eventIds": ["eventID1", "eventID2"]}};`

Comment: this is the format a service is looking for. Can not change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var x = {  
   "ma.addEvents":{  
      "ma.id":"my-id",
      "ma.eventIds":[  
         "eventID1",
         "eventID2"
      ]
   }
}
```

If you want to access, you have to use `[]` notation (`.` notation won't work, because of dots in keys) like

```
console.log(x["ma.addEvents"]["ma.id"])
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a square bracket notation:

```
var yourObject = {};
yourObject['ma.addEvents'] = {};
```

...and so on. Print the `ma.addEvents` attribute using

```
console.log(yourObject['ma.addEvents'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
var json_string = "{\"ma\.addEvents\":{\"ma\.id\":\"my-id\",\"ma\.eventIds\":[\"eventID1\",\"eventID2\"]}}";
```

The code above, when parsed to json (JSON.parse), will retrieve the same object that appears on your question.

Hope this helps,

Regards,

Marcelo

Comment: *"when parsed to json"* Uhm... the string *contains* JSON and `JSON.parse` converts it to an *object*.

Comment: You are right, what i tried to mean was the opposite. It should have said "when converted to an object (JSON.parse)...". But isn't it what this guy wants to do? May be i misunderstood the question.

Comment: I don't know what he wants to do, I just wanted to point out your "mistake". People are already confusing JavaScript objects with JSON, no need to confuse them even more :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = {  
   "ma.addEvents": {  
      "ma.id":"my-id",
      "ma.eventIds":[  
         "eventID1",
         "eventID2"
      ]
   }
}
```

Depends on what part you would like to add dynamically.

```
var obj = {};
obj["ma.addEvents"] = {
          "ma.id":"my-id",
          "ma.eventIds":[  
             "eventID1",
             "eventID2"
          ]
       };
obj["ma.addEvents"]["ma.eventIds"].push("someotherEvent");
```

Please take a look at the [documentation for accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Answer (score 1):

`ma` must be defined before you create `ma.addEvents` etc. The syntax might look like this:

```
// `ma` is an object
var ma = {
    // It contains an object called `addEvents`
    addEvents: {
        // Which contains a string `id` and an array `eventIds`
        id: "my-id",
        eventIds: [
            "eventId1",
            "eventId2"
        ]
    }
}
```

To create a blank object in `ma`, you could use the 'dot' syntax:

```
ma.newObject = {};
```

or square bracket notation:

```
ma["newObject"] = {};
```

I'm not entirely sure what your question is, are you looking to parse that JSON or to learn Javascript object syntax?